When will $\mathbb{Z}$ be a projective $\mathbb{Z}G$-module?
Let $G$ be a finite group and $\mathbb{Z}G$ be the integral group ring. I want to know for what groups $G$ we have the result.
It seems we should focus on the tautological short exact sequence for $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules
$$
0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}G \xrightarrow{\varepsilon} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0, 
$$
where the $\varepsilon$ is the augmentation map. We need to find a spilt map $\mu: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}G$ such that $\varepsilon \circ \mu= id_{\mathbb{Z}}$ for $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules.
I get an answer claiming that it will be true if and only if $G$ is trivial. If is trivial. For only if side, let $\mu(1)=x$. For any $\alpha=\sum r_ig_i$, we have $\mu(\alpha \cdot 1)=\mu(\sum r_i)= \sum r_i x= \alpha \mu(1)= \alpha x$. Then the answer said $(\alpha-\sum r_i)x=0 \Rightarrow \alpha=\sum r_i$. (I don't think this arrow is true since generally $\mathbb{Z}G$ has zero divisors.) And then (by the answer) $\alpha=\sum r_i \Rightarrow \sum r_ig_i=\sum r_i \Rightarrow \sum r_i(g_i-1)=0 \in I$. For those $\alpha$ which is not integer, by freeness of $I$ we must have $g_i=1$.
It seems this answer has the vital wrong point. Could we have a right answer?
Are there some description of zero divisor of $\mathbb{Z}G$? I know that $I$ and the norm element $\sum g$ for all $g \in G$ is the classical example. What I want to know is that whether all zero divisors are in these two forms?
By the way I suspect for cyclic $G$ we have $\mathbb{Z}G \cong I \oplus (\sum g)$ for $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules? How about general finite group $G$?
Thanks a lot.

I know there are questions with information about augmentation ideals that split out... I wish I could find them... they were interesting.

@rschwieb Yeah. Could you please vote for the question to make more people see it? Thanks a lot!

Write $x=\mu(1)=\sum x_gg$.  Since $(g-1)x=0$, we must have $x_g=x_1$ for all $g$, i.e. $x=x'(\sum_{g\in G} g)$ for some $x'\in \mathbb Z$.  This implies that $x'|G|=1$, so this can only be the case if $|G|=1$.

Thanks a lot!!! Do we have some idea about description of zero-divisors of $\mathbb{Z}G$?

By your answer I get in $\mathbb{Z}G$ the elements annihilated by augmentation ideal I must live in ($\sum g$).

@Rellw There are many other zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}G$.  For example, if you act trivially on any irreducible $\mathbb{Q}G$-module, then you're a zero divisor (the augmentation ideal acts trivially on the trivial representation, and the sum of g's acts trivially on all non-trivial simples).
